Por que en host local si puedo iniciar sesión, y cuando hosteo mi pagina en smarter no me deja iniciar sesión?
Cuando ejecuto mi pagina que esta codeada en la herramienta visual studio, esta echo en MVC no entity framework, asp.net c# js.
cuando la ejecuto en el host local osea desde mi pc funciona correctamente, puedo iniciar sesion y las acciones se reflejan en mi base de datos, pero cuando hosteo mi pagina el smarter al entrar a la pagina intento iniciar sesión y simplemente no pasa nada, si alguien sabe a que se debe agradeceria mucho.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Sin el codigo ni el log de errores pueden estar pasando mil cosas distintas...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
